# How to expand the character time format from "mm:ss" to "hh:mm:ss" in R

Tags: r

I need to add the hour to my time variable that currently has a format of "mm:ss" so that it becomes "hh:mm:ss" in R.

Comment: Can you give an example of what your current data looks like? Use `dput(head(mydata))` and paste what prints in the console into your question. I ask this, because the answer may depend on how your data is stored (character vs. POSIX, etc.).

Comment: Try something like (in `base`) `format(as.POSIXct("00:00",format="%M:%S"),"%H:%M:%S")`